# Кнопка для показа и скрытия блока div

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация, button

Нужна помощь в реализации кнопки, которая показывает и скрывает div блок.

Показывание сделать легко:

```
$(".button").click(function () {
$('#div_block').fadeIn(4000);
});
```

но вот как сделать затухание?

Comment: еще можно так - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/sjwmk7t9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [`fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/). Этот метод спрячет див, если он виден, и покажет, если не виден. Пример:

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    $('#div_block').fadeToggle(4000);
});
```

Comment: А ларчик просто открывался... Спасибо